# What is the default folder for websites on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

Looking to create a website with Hyde/Django to server static pages. Running Ubuntu.

Is there a certain folder or directory where I should be keeping this website? Should I just keep them in a "project" folder in `~`?

Just looking for a norm, first time playing with Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the normal setup is to go for `/var/www/html` after if you prefer to have this in your home directory you can use the userdir extension ([forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=421531) & [howto](http://myy.helia.fi/~karte/install_apache_on_ubuntu.html)).

Answer (score 1):

What web *server* are you using? With most, the default directory is in /var/www/, but of course this is totally configurable (e.g. in Apache 2, using the apache2.conf file or include files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled).  If you give more details you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Well, I would like to play with nginx or lighttpd. Something lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I make a distinction between "development" and "deployment".  I work on things in ~/project and I deploy them wherever they need to go - on my machine or on a remote server.  You can [read this](http://www.larrymyers.com/articles/using_hyde_for_static_sites.html) to see what others have done.